# how I can choose name of my app

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recording

I have a new application to help users recoding their voice , but when I searched on playstore I found many apps made the same things and their name were voice recorder , smart voice recorder....  so I want to know Are there any problems if I publish my app with the same name and when does my application name will become a violation of the laws of Google

Comment: I'm flagging this as unrelated to programming because it asks about Google's TOS rather than Android development. You might find better qualified help on a Google run forum or asking Google directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your apps name can be the same as an existing app (the package name can't), if the name is not protected by copyright.

I'm pretty sure no one can copyright `Recorder`, as it is a word, not a brand name.

Comment: are there any way for now if the name are copyright or not an thank you so much

Comment: I'm not an expert in copyright laws. As this is kinda off-topic here, i'd suggest you just google it.